# Regex Or condition matching order

Tags: regex

I have a question about the matching order of regex concatenated by `|` operator. I have this regex `" ?\p{L}+|\s+"`. For strings like `inputs = "    s"`, when I run `re.findall()`, it is split into `"    "` and `"s"`. My question is - how is the order determined? `" ?\p{L}+"` should give `" s"`, why is the space deleted in the final result? To clarify, I am using python regex.

To reproduce:

```py
import regex as re

pat = re.compile(r" ?\p{L}+|\s+")
inputs = "    s"
print(re.findall(pat, inputs))
```

Many thanks to your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Working of regex  `?\p{L}+|\s+` matches against input: `"    s"`:**

- Matching of regular expression matching is from left to right.
- First it attempts to find a match for first alternation option  `\p{L}+` in input and as you notice there is no match at the start of the input for this option.
- Next it attempts to find a match for `\s+` and that results in a success hence first match is `"    "`.
- Now 5 spaces have been consumed in this match and pointer moves to letter `s`.
- Then regex engine attempts to match `s` using alternations again.
- This time  `?\p{L}+` is successful in matching `s` hence second match is `s`.
- Regex engine stops at this point since it has reached to the end of input.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a negative lookahead pattern to avoid `\s+` consuming the whitespace that `?\p{L}+` would match:

```
pat = re.compile(r" ?\p{L}+|\s+(?!\p{L})")
```

Demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing/WeeklyVividInverse

Comment: Thanks too! The big problem I have is I am using google re2, which for reasons do not support lookahead.....

Comment: Your question states, "To clarify, I am using python regex.", and includes a snippet of Python code that uses the `regex` package that does support lookaheads. And now you're saying you're using Google RE2. Please make sure to include the right details in your question in the future so that people can spend time helping your actual problem. With the limitations of RE2, I don't think it is possible to have one single regex that extracts the desired strings in one step.

Comment: Thanks for raising the concern. But please note that my question is not about "how I should split the string as XXX", but asking about "how the matching order is determined". In its context I am asking with python regex package.